# Periodic overhead when using tensorflow dataset for model training on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, overhead

As you can see it in the following code, I am trying to train a simple model on Tensorflow with a Tensorflow Dataset. The dataset is pretty huge and I suffle , repeat and batch it in order to do a stochastic gradien descent for training my model.

But I can observe a period overhead of the optimisation step (it is sess.run(train) in my code).

As you can see it here, every 5 steps, it needs 3s instead of 0.5 to do the optimisation.

Step  105  duration :  3.5233473777770996

Step  106  duration :  0.5653283596038818

Step  107  duration :  0.5391891002655029

Step  108  duration :  0.5480048656463623

Step  109  duration :  0.0415492057800293

Step  110  duration :  3.032115936279297

Step  111  duration :  0.5407207012176514

Step  112  duration :  0.5276811122894287

Step  113  duration :  0.5448746681213379

Step  114  duration :  0.04253268241882324

Step  115  duration :  3.1273345947265625

Moreover my GPU is almost all the time at 0% utilisation with around 90% of the memory used.

It seems that this overhead arrived when the Iterator finish to see all the dataset.

I am using Python 3.6 with Tensorflow 1.4 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Do you have any idea how I can speed up my training ?

Best,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os, time, multiprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def _floats_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=value.reshape(-1)))


def parser(record):
    num_features = 2000
    size_group = 300
    num_classes= 10
    class_indice = 0
    keys_to_features={
                'X': tf.FixedLenFeature([size_group*num_features],tf.float32),
                'label' : tf.FixedLenFeature([num_classes],tf.float32)}
    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, keys_to_features)

    label = parsed['label']
    label = tf.slice(label,[class_indice],[1])
    label = tf.squeeze(label) # To get a vector one dimension
    X = parsed['X']
    X= tf.reshape(X, [size_group,num_features])
    return X, label


def test_train_w_dataset():

    # Definition of the size 
    num_features = 2000
    num_ex = 2000
    size_group = 300
    num_classes = 10
    batch_size= 480
    max_iters = 300
    buffer_size = 10000

# Creation of the Dataset 
filename_tfrecords = 'tmp.tfrecords'
if not(os.path.isfile(filename_tfrecords)): # If the file doesn't exist we will create it
    print("Start creating the Dataset")
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename_tfrecords)

    for i in range(num_ex):
        if i % 1000 == 0: print("Step :",i)
        X = np.random.normal(size=(size_group,num_features))
        vectors =  2*np.random.randint(0,2,(num_classes,1))-1
        features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                    'X': _floats_feature(X),
                    'label' : _floats_feature(vectors)})
        example = tf.train.Example(features=features)       
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
else:
    print("The dataset tfrecords already exist")

train_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename_tfrecords)
num_proc = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parser,
                                    num_parallel_calls=num_proc)
dataset_shuffle = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size,
                                             reshuffle_each_iteration=True) 
dataset_shuffle = dataset_shuffle.batch(batch_size)
dataset_shuffle = dataset_shuffle.repeat() 
dataset_shuffle = dataset_shuffle.prefetch(batch_size) 
shuffle_iterator = dataset_shuffle.make_initializable_iterator()
X_, y_ = shuffle_iterator.get_next()

W=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_features], stddev=1.),name="weights")
W=tf.reshape(W,(1,1,num_features))
Prod=tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(W,X_),axis=2)
Max=tf.reduce_max(Prod,axis=1)
Tan= tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf.tanh(Max),y_))
loss= tf.add(Tan,tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(W,W)))

LR = 0.01
restarts = 1
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(LR) 
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)  
print("The graph is defined")
sess = tf.Session(config=config)

durationTab = []

for essai in range(restarts+1):
    # To do need to reinitialiszed
    t0 = time.time()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(shuffle_iterator.initializer)
    t1 = time.time()
    duration = t1 - t0
    print('Duration of initialization : ',duration)
    for step in range(max_iters):
        t0 = time.time()
        sess.run(train)
        t1 = time.time()
        duration = t1 - t0
        print("Step ",str(step),' duration : ',duration)
        durationTab += [duration]


plt.plot(durationTab)
plt.ylabel('Duration')
plt.xlabel('Iteration')
plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    test_train_w_dataset()
```

Answer (score 0):

For GPU utilization, make sure you use the gpu optimized binary. Check operation placement (in tensorboard for example). Force placement of the operations on the gpu (see tf.device).

For the periodic spikes there could be a few reasons:

- Other processes block access to CPU/GPU/RAM/Disk and you need to wait for that to pass. You can try to kill other superfluous tasks that might be running on your system.
- You run out of ram. Check how much of the swap space is used. If it's growing when you run then the spikes might be just system thrashing, though it looks too well behaved for that.
- Disk access. You mentioned that this sees to correlate with looping over the data. It could be the system just needs to read the data again so you need to wait for the disk, though usually that's not visible. You could speed it up by making sure the data is contiguous on hard-drive, move it to an SSD or RAM.

Since a lot of the reasons have to do with RAM, you should probably try a smaller model (smaller batches, less layers, less nodes/layer) and see if it goes away. If it does then you need to go out and buy more RAM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I am using the Tensorflow GPU optimized binary.
Moreover I tried to move my TFrecords dataset from the HDD to the SSD, it changes nothing.The RAM isn't full neither the GPU memory.

The model is really simple with only one layer. The problem seems to come from the [Tensorflow Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) use and that's strange because it seems to be the role of the Dataset to deal with the feeding of the GPU efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding dataset_shuffle = dataset_shuffle.cache() between the batch and repeat function remove those periodic overhead. Nevertheless, I am not sure that the Dataset is fully read with the use of this command.